# Ruby to Scala code translation

Tags: ruby, scala

I'm converting some code from Ruby to Scala. Problem is that I never programmed Ruby in my life. It's going well, but now I reached two lines that I don't understand.
How can I convert the last 2 Ruby lines to Scala?

```
  num_obs = pop.first[:objectives].size
  num_obs.times do |i|
    min = pop.min{|x,y| x[:objectives][i]<=>y[:objectives][i]}
    max = pop.max{|x,y| x[:objectives][i]<=>y[:objectives][i]}
    /* do sth. with min and max */
  end
```

pop is Vector[Map[String, Any]]

Comment: What is `i`? Is it bound to anything in the current scope? While I'm by no means a Ruby expert, the `:objectives` thing looks much more like a symbol, so the corresponding Scala-type should be `Vector[Map[Symbol, Any]]`.

Comment: yeah, but in my scala code i'm using Vector[Map[String, Any]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole `|x,y| f(x) <=> f(y)` thing seems to just compare `x` and `y` by some property `f`, and the `<=>` returns `-1, 0, 1`. The same thing can be expressed much easier if instead of providing a `compare` method with return values `-1, 0, 1`, we simply compare by `f`. In Scala, this would be something like:

```
val pop: Vector[Map[String, Any]] = ???
val num_obs: Int = ???
for (i <- 0 until num_obs) {
  val min = pop.minBy(_("objectives").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]](i))
  val max = pop.maxBy(_("objectives").asInstanceOf[Vector[Int]](i))
  /* do sth. with min and max */
}
```

Note that I've replaced symbols `:objectives` by a String, even though Scala also has `Symbol`-type (the corresponding symbol would be `'objectives`). I've also assumed that the values in the map are something like vectors of integers (the indexing with `i` doesn't make any sense otherwise).

Comment: Firstly thank you, I'll try that, but now I have a question. What kind of datatype are max and min?
Because next line is 
`rge = max[:objectives][i] - min[:objectives][i]`
So i think max and min should be Vectors aswell

Comment: @flyist `Map[String, Any]`, I guess... If this doesn't make any sense at all, then I'd have to take another look into ruby documentation. The variable `min` is something like "the map with the smallest `i`-th component of the vector `:objectives`". The variables `min` and `max` should **not** be vectors, they should be maps, otherwise you can't access `:objectives` component of them.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. I think you solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SimpleLime is `#` something like the identity-function, and `=>` is your own informal notation for *"evaluates to"*? If `pop` is a vector with maps of type `Map[String, Any]`, then `min` and `max` should also be `Map[String, Any]`, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @SimpleLime Oh, yeah, obvious, it's a comment, of course. xD Now you see my level of expertise in Ruby in all its glory^^ xD Thank you for the example! :)

Comment: I have just checked and min and max are `Map[String, Any]` and `max("objectives")` is a Vector. That is why this works for me. Thank you bro.

Comment: @flyist Hey, awesome, that's apparently my first answer for a question tagged "ruby", interesting...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Can you help me with another? 
`fronts[last_front].sort! {|x,y| crowded_comparison_operator(x,y)}`
The function `crowded_comparison_operator(x,y)` is like a compare, returns -1, 0 or 1.
last_front is an Int

Comment: @flyist Sry, didn't see that comment yesterday. I see that you decided to ask it as a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50317903/ruby-to-scala-code-translation-sorting-in-scala). I don't know, maybe I gonna take a look at it, unless someone else is faster.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is good, but I believe the code can be much simpler. The Ruby code is pretty bad (not only that, it is even syntactically illegal!), and I wouldn't try to translate it at all, it would probably be much better to rewrite it instead of translating it.

The two specific lines you are asking about are just a very convoluted way of writing

```
min, max = pop.minmax_by { |x| x[:objectives][i] }
```

However, since `min` and `max` are local variables of the block, they go out of scope immediately at the end of the block, and since they aren't used anywhere else, the entire loop is actually just a no-op. (Unless `Enumerable#min` or `Enumerable#max` or `Hash#[]` / `Array#[]` have been overridden to have some kind of side-effect, which would be *really* strange.)

`Integer#times` evaluates to `self`, so the entire thing is actually just equivalent to:

```
pop.first[:objectives].size
```

The Scala equivalent of which is

```
pop.head('objectives).size
```

But *really*, the Ruby code you posted is syntactically invalid, so it is in fact not Ruby code *at all*, and there is no Scala equivalent.

Comment: On *"since they aren't used anywhere else, the entire loop is actually just a no-op"*: since the `end` is not visible, I assume that the block does not end after these two lines. An earlier edition of the question included only the last two lines, until I asked what the `i` is supposed to be. So, it's obviously incomplete. Is it the case that it cannot be extended to syntactically valid code?

Comment: There are a myriad of different ways how this can be made syntactically valid, each of which will have a different translation to Scala. One such possibility is that there is an `end` missing after the lines in the question, in which case my answer minus the last paragraph stands. `Integer#times` is only useful for the side-effects of the block passed to it, since it simply evaluates to `self`, but the block the OP shows has no side-effects.