# Ruby to Scala code translation - Sorting in Scala

Tags: ruby, scala, sorting, translate, code-translation

I'm converting some code from Ruby to Scala. Problem is that I never programmed Ruby in my life. It's going well, but now I reached a line that I don't know because I'm new in Scala and I don't understand the sorting mechanism.
So I want to translate this ruby line to scala:

```
fronts[last_front].sort! {|x,y| crowded_comparison_operator(x,y)}
```

`fronts` is `Vector[Vector[Map[String, Any]]]`

`last_front` is an `Int`

`crowded_comparison_operator(x,y)` returns -1, 0 or 1, x and y are `Map[String, Any]`

Comment: Have you looked at [the docs for sortBy](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#sortBy[B](f:A=>B)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Repr)?

Comment: Sure, but `crowded_comparison_operator(x,y)` takes two arguments and that is confusing to me. Sorry i'm a bit noob in Scala/Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities with standard Scala collections:

- Convert the `-1, 0, 1` output of `crowded_comparison_operator` into a boolean that tells you whether the first element is less than the second element, then use `sortWith`.
- define a new `Ordering`, pass it explicitly to the `sorted` method.

---

**The `sortWith` method**

The first element is less than the second element if and only if `crowded_comparison_operator` returns -1, so you could do this:

```
fronts(last_front).sortWith{ (x, y) => crowded_comparison_operator(x, y) < 0 }
```

---

**Defining an `Ordering` for `sorted`**

The `sorted` method takes an implicit `Ordering` parameter. You can define your own custom ordering, and pass it explicitly:

```
import scala.math.Ordering

fronts(last_front).sorted(new Ordering[Vector[Map[String, Any]]] {
  def compare(
    x: Vector[Map[String, Any]], 
    y: Vector[Map[String, Any]]
  ): Int = crowded_comparison_operator(x, y)
})
```

or shorter, with scala versions supporting [SAM](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#lambda-syntax-for-sam-types) (since 2.11.5, if I remember correctly):

```
fronts(last_front).sorted(
  (x: Vector[Map[String, Any], y: Vector[Map[String, Any]]) => 
    crowded_comparison_operator(x, y)
)
```

Note that, as @mikej has pointed out, Ruby's `sort!` sorts the array in-place. This cannot work for an immutable vector, so you have to adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: This answer is great! The only thing to add is that `sort!` in Ruby performs an in place sort. There is no equivalent in Scala so you might need to adjust other parts of your Scala to allow for a new `Vector[Map[String, Any]]` being returned rather than the original being modified.

Comment: @mikej Ah, thanks, that's an important difference. Unfortunately, this cannot be changed easily, since `Vector` is immutable. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: As of [Scala 2.12](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/), you can just write `fronts(last_front).sorted(crowded_comparison_operator)` for the last one (assuming `crowded_comparison_operator` is a method; if it's a function, you might need `fronts(last_front).sorted(crowded_comparison_operator(_, _))`).

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Thanks, updated. I assume that `crowded_comparison_operator` is not an actual method name, but rather a placeholder for a lengthy body of a ruby in-line function literal. I therefore included the explicit type annotations `Vector[Map[String, Any]]`, because otherwise the compiler whines at me because of "error: missing parameter type".